# UWP publisher, which certificate type should I buy?

Tags: uwp, certificate, publisher

[image]

In the above screenshot, clicking on the "choose certificate" button prompts for a certificate :

- Create test certificate (that's what I usually do)
- Select from file
- Pick from certificate store

I want to get a real certificate from a certification company. Which type of certificate should I buy ?

Thank you.

EDIT: my real question is: can someone point me to one or more products which could fit here ?

EDIT: I have tried to use the .pfx file from my IT but this didn't work (Error = Manifest designer could not import the certificate). I must add that this application is meant to be side-loaded by our clients, not downloaded/installed from Microsoft's store. Would that change anything to the process ? 
I have recently upgraded to VS2019 and the "choose certificate" button doesn't allow me to pick a cert using the file system anymore, and does not propose to create a new test certificate either...

Comment: Just create your own? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing

Comment: @McNline Thx for your reply. I know how to create a self-signed certificate. Those are for testing applications and deployment, are valid only 1 year, and cannot be trusted. I edited my question for clarity.